# Multi threading Split and download large file and merge file into one using Java Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to download a large file (Any file format) in android application using multithreading like splitting and start a separate download request to the server and get the data in different parts and merge it back to the single file.

If anybody know how to split and start in multi threading please share the samples or tutorials. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution??